# TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

Here's what my dataframe looks like:

```
intrate.head()
Out[83]: 
         Date  UNRATE
0  1954-07-01    0.80
1  1954-08-01    1.22
2  1954-09-01    1.06
3  1954-10-01    0.85
4  1954-11-01    0.83
```

The years goes all the way to 2019 and I'm trying to resample it to individual years.

I had converted the Date column to Datetime as shown below.

```
Out[86]: 
Date      datetime64[ns]
UNRATE           float64
dtype: object
```

The problem is when I'm trying to resample:

```
intratey = intrate.resample('A').ffill()
```

I get the error message of:

```
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) requires the *index* to be datetime format. So if you select your date column to be the index it should work. You can do that by using [set_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html).

Comment: Thank you Joseph!  I can't believe I missed that.